# MySQL slow query

Tags: mysql, performance

This is my first time posting here. I am new to MySQL and trying to learn it as fast as possible but this issue is causing a problem to production and need to reach out for help.

This server is running Suse linux and has a MariaDB 5.5.46. We have been having a huge spike in threads on this active server and I have been digging into this for a little while. I have used Jet Profiler to get a more visual idea of what is going on while looking into this matter and a few days ago I saw this spike live on the server shooting up to 600 threads for about 2 minutes. Thanks to that i have isolated a query that even in the CLI is taking 45 to 57 sec to complete.

This is the offending query that i have pulled out of the Jet Profiler. it is coming from a web site pulling a list off the source for an external person to view the contents. The active server that it is pulling from is phone system.

```
SELECT CONCAT( DATE(call_date),'<br/>', TIME(call_date) ) as DateTime
    , vlog.campaign_id AS Campaign
    , CONCAT(emp.full_name,' [',vlog.user,']') AS 'Rep'
    , CONCAT(lead.first_name,' ',lead.last_name) as 'Name'
    , CONCAT(lead.state,'/',lead.city) AS 'State-City'  , lead.lead_id
    , vlog.status as CallSts
    , lead.status as LeadSts
    , vlog.phone_number AS 'Phone'
    , timediff(end_time,start_time) as 'Length'
    , location
FROM
    vicidial_log as vlog 
    LEFT JOIN recording_log as rlog  ON vlog.uniqueid = rlog.vicidial_id
    LEFT JOIN vicidial_list as lead  ON vlog.lead_id = lead.lead_id 
    LEFT JOIN vicidial_users as emp  ON emp.user      = rlog.user
WHERE
    date(vlog.call_date) <= '2016-03-11'
    AND vlog.status <> 'INCALL'
    AND vlog.length_in_sec > 10
    AND vlog.campaign_id like 'AG%' 
    AND location IS NOT NULL
   AND rlog.end_time IS NOT NULL
```

Here is the EXPLAIN addition.

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID | select_type | table |  type  |    possible_keys     |     key     | key_len |            ref            |  rows   |                               Extra                                 |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | rlog  | range  | filename,vicidial_id | vicidial_id |      63 | NULL                      | 1040870 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | vlog  | eq_ref | PRIMARY              | PRIMARY     |      62 | asterisk.rlog.vicidial_id |       1 | Using where                                                         |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | lead  | eq_ref | PRIMARY              | PRIMARY     |       4 | asterisk.vlog.lead_id     |       1 |                                                                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | emp   | eq_ref | user                 | user        |      62 | asterisk.rlog.user        |       1 | Using where                                                         |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: At least the LEFT join on `recording_log` and `vicidial_users` are wrong, it's actually Inner joins (which table is `location` coming from?).

Comment: Adapted the query to use the INNER for this part of the query and it still took 47.85 sec. I will track down the table that the inner join is using and report back.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: What tables are `location` and `end_time` in?  Change the query to add aliases in front of them.

Comment: On what portion would you like me to show the Create table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like indexes are not properly used.

You have 6 `WHERE` (`AND`) clauses, each of them should be analyzed from an index selection perspective :

**clause 1**: `DATE(vlog.call_date) <= '2016-03-11'`

This one won't be a good candidate because:

1. you cast your `call_date` with a `DATE()` function, making any index on this column totally unusable.
2. a `call_date` lower than a recent date would not filter a lot of records anyway since most of the calls would likely be in the range

**clause 2**: `vlog.status <> 'INCALL'`

A not equal clause won't be able to use any `status` based index as far as I can tell.

**clause 3**: `vlog.length_in_sec > 10`

I can imagine most of the calls would last more than 10s, so an numerical index based on this column would probably not filter many records, if ever defined. May depend on actual recorded data though.

**clause 4**: `vlog.campaign_id like 'AG%'`

I like this one. A string based index would filter on the compaigns stating with these two characters. If text were equally distributed upon alphabetical letters — [LIKE clause being case insensitive](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html) — you would have a 26x26=612 factor filter. It's less probable, but I would at least say a 100 factor, which is kind of a good start.

You'd still have to add the index on that column if not existing, and also make sure you would launch the query with at least 2 letters, to be efficient.

**clause 5**: `location IS NOT NULL`

Nullable columns can be indexed and filtered on null values, but they are arguably very common values that would not filter a lot of records. I would preferably follow the clause 4 lead.

**clause 6**: `rlog.end_time IS NOT NULL`

Same as clause 5.

To summarize, I would add an index on `compaign_id` and see what happens.

Hope that helps.

Comment: 26*26=676.  52*52 is what you wanted _if_ the collation is `..._ci`.  But your final conclusion (100 factor) is actually pretty correct for the most common 2-letter pair of a non-evenly-distibuted list.

Comment: What kind of key should i add to the campaign_id index ?

Comment: A standard one-column key with the following syntax : `ALTER TABLE vlog ADD INDEX (campaign_id)`.

Comment: I added an index to the corresponding table that the relation of vlog was using and it helped. it brought the query down to 33.69 secs. It seems like we are moving in the right direction.

Comment: Indexing has definitely helped. I indexed server columns until i hit a 0.01 sec time. And now i am working on minimizing this. So far i have found that the biggest index that changes the time of the query from 48 ish sec to 4.26 sec is length_in_sec column. This is after i have removed all indexes and flushed the cache.

Comment: There are 2 columns that have VARCHAR would it be best to apply a FULLTEXT index on this column or just a standard index ?

Comment: With 2 indexes this query is now at 0.00 to 0.01. Thank you for your help I have been able to isolate the need for the indexes to call_date and length_in_sec. That is a vast difference from where i started.

Comment: Great, I'm glad you found a solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `LEFT` except when you expect it to do something.  In your case, `AND rlog.end_time IS NOT NULL` effectively turns the `LEFT JOIN` into `JOIN`.  I can't tell about the others, but it could matter to the performance.

Each of the columns here *might* be useful as an index.  Add 4 single-column indexes in order to give the Optimizer some choices.  Hopefully it will pick the most selective.

```
    vlog.call_date < '2016-03-12'  -- note the changes
AND vlog.status <> 'INCALL'
AND vlog.length_in_sec > 10
AND vlog.campaign_id like 'AG%'
```

Once you see from `EXPLAIN` which index it picks, make a 4-column composite index starting with that column.  (If `location` is also in that table, include it, too.)  The hope here is that ICP will kick in for the index scan and be more efficient than just a single-column index.

62-byte ids???  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so I can criticize your keys.

It says "using temporary, using filesort", yet I see nothing in the query that necessitates such.  Are you sure that query and that `EXPLAIN` go together?

Comment: I love the '_Hopefully_ it will pick the most selective' part! As a matter of fact, MySQL has been surprisingly worse than expected in my experience, as far as index selection is concerned.

Comment: LOL.  That particular pattern is especially bad.  5.7 has improvements, and _may_ do better on this "toss a 4-sided coin" optimization problem.

Answer (score 0):

When a query take so much time, it often means that the database is executing a linear table scan rather than an indexed access.

However, to help you, I need more data. You had to use `EXPLAIN` and `PROFILING` to extract the required informations.

EXPLAIN is simple to grasp: it print how the query planner intends to run your query. Execute `EXPLAIN <your query here>` and report back the output.

PROFILING is a little more complex. To use it, you had to:

- enable profiling via `SET profiling=1`
- execute your query
- list the profiled queries (with their IDs) using `SHOW profiles`
- print detailed information executing `SHOW profile FOR query <query_id>`

Execute these commands and report back the output.

Comment: I have add the EXPLAIN portion in the original part. I Will have to add the second portion tomorrow morning. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I have tried setting profiling as you have suggested but i come up with an issue.It seems that the database does not have profiling enabled.

Comment: I have grabbed a tool set from Percona and run the pt-query-digest. This has given me some results back. Would that be helpfully.

Comment: Can you EXPLAIN removing the `AND rlog.end_time IS NOT NULL` clause?